# Htaccess: exculde files within directory from being rewrited by any htaccess rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

the rewrite rules in my htaccess file are:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z-]+/[0-9A-Za-z-]+.html)$ /event.php?file=$1 [L]
```

i have directory called `pop` and i want to exclude files in from being affected by the last rule in htaccess.

files in the pop directory are something like:

```
en-kijys-umn-satam-27599506296230.html
```

i have tried adding this cond. but no luck

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/pop [NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work. Try it this way.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pop [NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z-]+/[0-9A-Za-z-]+.html)$ /event.php?file=$1 [L]
```

Also clear your browser cache or try in another browser to make sure the form rules aren't cached.